# Scala Spark IntelliJ Idea development process

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am currently using spark to write my dimensional data model and we are currently uploading the jar to an AWS EMR cluster to test. However, this is tedious and time consuming for testing and building tables.

I would like to know what others are doing to speed up their development. The possibilities I came across in my research is running spark jobs directly from the IDE with Intellij Idea and I would like to know other development processes that are being used where it's faster to develop.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028350/spark-local-standalone-cluster-with-intellij-idea-main-function-scala/66030438#66030438

Answer (score 0):

The ways I have had tried till now are:

1. Installing spark and hdfs on two or three commodity PCs and test the code before submitting it on the cluster.
2. Running the code on the single node to avoid dummy mistakes.
3. Submitting the jar file on the cluster.

The similar part in the first and third method is making the jar file which may takes a lot of time. The second one is not suitable to find and fix the bugs and problems and raise on distributed running environments.